# Prefixing @keyframes mixin?

Tags: css, sass

In pure SASS, is it possible to have something like this?

```
$prefixed: "", "-webkit-"

    @each $p in $prefixed
        @#{$p}keyframes animation
            0%
                bottom: 0
                #{$p}animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.215, 0.610, 0.355, 1.000)
            100%
                bottom: 60px
```

to output as this:

```
@-webkit-keyframes animation
    0%
        bottom: 0
        -webkit-animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.215, 0.610, 0.355, 1.000)
    100%
        bottom: 60px

@keyframes animation
    0%
        bottom: 0
        animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.215, 0.610, 0.355, 1.000)
    100%
        bottom: 60px
```

Comment: Why not just use Bourbon?

Comment: why? That doesn't make sense. Reinventing the wheel is silly.

Comment: @MightyPork On large projects it is not up to you to decide how things are going to be done. At least on a framework level. Do you know anyway to make something like this work in pure SASS?

Comment: Yes, copy it from bourbon :D Bourbon is a SASS mixin library, it IS pure SASS.